# How to manipulate the master in an SplitView iPad app?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I created a Split View-based application with Xcode 4. Now I get how the content is populated and how information is pushed to the detail view, but is there any way to actually manipulate the master view, i.e. add a row to the table?

In all the tutorials I found, this is not explained and I'm kinda confused. :-)

Thanks and regards
Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *master view* is yet another `UITableViewController`, so managing the table is done in its `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method.

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial) is step by step introduction to `UISplitView`.

Answer (score 1):

The rows are added according to what you populate the table with. I’m not quite sure what you mean by the “master view.” Is this the window/view controller you’re using for a data source?

You might want to look into Beginning iPhone Development, by Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche, which goes into exhaustive detail on navigation controllers and how to populate their child views. The principles are pretty much the same in Cocoa.

Comment: It sounds like he's referring to master/detail. The detail view is the one that takes up most of the space, with the master view along the left side. (Also, Cocoa is for Mac programming; this question is about Cocoa Touch, so the contents of that book are directly relevant here.)